# Javascript not return current value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, razor

Here is my code

```
<script>
        setInterval(function () {
            var newCount = '@(new ShipperHN.DAO.PostDAO().getTotalPost())';
            var curCount = '@Session["curCount"]';
            alert(newCount +"\t"+ curCount);
            if (newCount > curCount) {
                document.getElementById("checkNewPosts").innerHTML = (newCount - curCount) + " new posts unread";
            }
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

---

`new ShipperHN.DAO.PostDAO().getTotalPost()` //change by time, get from a sqlServer host

but i always get only 1 value

How can I get current value?

thanks!

Comment: I think you need to type cast your session variable to desired type..

Comment: Thanks but It still works fine @mmushtaq